# Event handler/raiser code snippet

Tags: c#, events, conventions

I would like to hear opinions on below code snippet. Is there anything that can be improved? Is the event handler/raiser naming following best practices? I know it is not that useful to handle and raise events in the same class but this is just a snippet.

```
public class MyControl
{
    public MyControl()
    {
        this.LogWritten += this.HandleMyControlLogWritten;
    }

    // Event handler
    void HandleMyControlLogWritten(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    // Event object
    public event Action<object, EventArgs> LogWritten;

    // Event raiser
    protected virtual void OnLogWritten(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.LogWritten != null)
        {
            this.LogWritten(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main change I'd recommend would be to get a copy of the event handler:

```
// Event raiser
protected virtual void OnLogWritten(EventArgs e)
{
    var handler = this.LogWritten;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, e);
    }
}
```

This is important if you're planning to (eventually) use this class in a multi-threaded scenario.  As such, I find that it's a good "best practice" to get into the habit of using.  The issue is that, when using in multiple threads, without creating the copy, it's possible that the only "handler" attached could unsubscribe between the null check and the invocation, which would cause a runtime error.  By copying to a temporary variable (the `var handler = this.LogWritten;`) line, you're effectively creating a "snapshot" of the subscriber list, and *then* checking it for null and invoking if required.

The other change is in the event declaration itself.  Instead of using `Action<T1,T2>`:

```
// Event object
public event Action<object, EventArgs> LogWritten;
```

I would recommend using [`EventHandler<TEventArgs>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x.aspx) (if you want to use a custom `EventArgs` subclass) or [`EventHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler.aspx) (for standard `EventArgs`).  These are more "standard practice", and will be what other developers expect:

```
// Event object
public event EventHandler LogWritten;
```

Comment: While I agree, it's probably worth explaining *why* that's a good idea.

Comment: @Jon: Yeah, I was writing it up at the time ;)

Comment: Oh nice, almost forgot that it wouldn't be possible alter a delegate's invocation list while invoking the delegate. Slick reminder.

Comment: @Reed, outstanding answer much appreciated. By the way any thoughts on handler naming: 'HandleMyControlLogWritten' vs 'MyControlLogWrittenHandle' or else..

Comment: @Teoman: It's private, so naming is really up to you.  I often do "RaiseLogWritten" for the method to raise the event, and "OnLogWritten" for the handler...